# Kernel version is still 3.16 on Freya 0.3.1

Tags: kernel

> At the heart of this upgrade is the latest Hardware Enablement stack
>   from Ubuntu 14.04.3. It includes version **3.19** of the Linux kernel and
>   an updated Mesa that fixes the dreaded “double cursor” glitch.

```
$ uname -a
Linux alex0007 3.16.0-48-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 20 23:03:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the official elementary blog:

> If you’re already running Freya, you will already have received all of the above (with the exception of the newly added hardware support) in your regular updates.

If you really need kernel 3.19 try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [update kernel and mesa](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) without reinstall the system.

Enter following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64, for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved command, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386
```

**Warning!** Be careful and attentive to this, the system can fail. Check packages that will be removed before pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>. In my case, everything went well and it looks like this:

```
maxim@ProBook:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgbm1-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libllvm3.6 libxatracker2-lts-vivid
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-vivid-tools xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
  gpointing-device-settings touchfreeze firmware-linux
Recommended packages:
  libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-vivid
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-lts-utopic libgbm1-lts-utopic
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
  libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic
  libopenvg1-mesa-lts-utopic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic
  libxatracker2-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-utopic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgbm1-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libllvm3.6 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libxatracker2-lts-vivid linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
0 upgraded, 44 newly installed, 39 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 308 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```