# Can't install newest hardware-enablement stack

Tags: release-freya, updates

I tried to install newest HWE stack to get rid of the double cursor bug. As suggested in [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1781/2283) I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

which resulted in tons of unmet dependencies / broken packages.  [Full log.](http://pastebin.com/t7BS8H62)

Is there anything I can do bar clean install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are using applications with 32bit libraries (like Skype, Wine, Steam).
Uninstall all 32bit based software and try to upgrade your HWE-stack again, it should work now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, will there be any issues reinstalling those apps after upgrading the HWE stack?

Comment: No, at least no for Skype. It's up and running like it was before the update.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by purging all the *lts-utopic packages before upgrading again.