# Problems with High CPU use when Elementary OS is Idle and Unused

Tags: gala

I've been seeing something kind of odd behavior from of my elementary OS install:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbS8k.png

When I left the machine running as a guest on my VMWare ESXi server overnight, it would plateau in CPU use once every ten minutes or so. Other VMs, like Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14 will typically max out at like 0.2 GHz when idle, but Gala seems to be pushing this elementary OS install to five times that amount periodically.

Any ideas what could cause this? The big leap in use on the right hand side is when I logged in and after ten minutes ran `gala --replace &` to reset Gala, which had consumed like 40 minutes of CPU time in the past day of being idle with no applications running. Another ten minutes after restarting Gala and it's running smooth and clear at under 1% total system CPU-use.

Should I use crontab to force-reset Gala every time I go idle? Anyone have some ideas what might cause this? I've had problems in the past with high idle-CPU use on elementary OS installs (sitting at 1+GHz when not in use), but this is the first time it made a time-variable pattern like the above screenshot.

Comment: What version are you using? 0.3 or 0.3.1?

Comment: This was a also a constant issue for me with 0.3 that I fixed by updating the kernel and mesa like [this.](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/kernel-version-is-still-3-16-on-freya-0-3-1/1781#1781) I eventually reinstalled with 0.31 (for other reasons) and the issue hasn't cropped up, presumably because it already includes that updated kernel and packages.

Answer (score 2):

A recent article claims a bug exists that allows Samba to max out 100% cpu usage, if you re not using Samba or any of it's features change the permissions so it wont start on it's own.

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse
```

Answer (score -1):

Same bug in Elementary OS 5.1 too.
`sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse` is a temporary fix. Looks like elementary OS team needs a decade to fix this bug since this issue was reported 5-6 years ago (..)